# Create comma-delimited string

Tags: javascript

I'm looking to find a neat way to create a comma-delimited string from an array. This is how I'm doing it now...

```
for(i=0;i<10;i++)
{
   str = str + ',' + arr[i];
}
str=str.substring(1)
return str;
```

... but it feels a bit untidy.

Comment: http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_join.asp

Comment: Six great answers in three minutes. This place is amazing. Thank you all.

Comment: Just on a side note, instead of `str = str  +` you could use `str +=`.

Answer (score 70, accepted):

`Array.prototype.join()` is what you're looking for:

```
arr.join(',');
```

https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/join

---

```
var arr = ['Hi', 'I', 'am', 'a', 'comma', 'separated', 'list'];

arr.join(',');  // === "Hi,I,am,a,comma,separated,list"
```

Comment: And if it's a comma you want, you don't need to give it a parameter at all -- `','` is the default separator, Section 15.4.4.5 of [the spec](http://www.ecma-international.org/publications/standards/Ecma-262.htm). It doesn't hurt for clarity, though.

Comment: @T.J.: good point. Anyway I guess I wouldn't rely on that if its important to me to have an array joined with a comma (more precisely, I wouldn't dare all implementations).

Comment: I've never met an implementation that got it wrong, but I have *nothing* against the clarity provided by being explicit. (I'm a big fan of clarity.)

Answer (score 2):

Use the join method:

```
arr.join(',');
```

Answer (score 2):

you have to use

> var joinedstr = myarray.join(',');

Answer (score 1):

I think there is something like `array.join(',')` where **array** is your array variable instance.

Answer (score 1):

Use the join function:

`myarray.join(',');`