# Javascript how to transform an array of objects

Tags: javascript, jquery, underscore.js

I have an array of company objects and now I want to create a comma separated string of "companyId"s

```
 var company ={companyId:'', companyName:''}, 
 var companies: [company1, company2, ..]

 expectedStringResult ="companyId1,companyId2,companyId3"
```

I see this example in SO:

[Create comma-delimited string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5166385/create-comma-delimited-string)

But the answer assumes you have strings in your array and not objects like company, is there a way to neatly accomplish this without a for loop in javascript/jquery? (like you apply transform function in Java guava library)

**Edit: I ended up using underscoreJS pluck function:**

```
 _.pluck(companies, "companyId").join()
```

this does not crash if companies is null and much clean

But the accepted answer below with jQuery also works well.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
companies.map(function(item){return item.companyId;}).join(',');
```

Or for old browsers

```
$.map(companies, function(item){return item.companyId;}).join(',');
```

Comment: tnx and this will return a string? and as a reminder I don't want my original companies array is modified

Comment: This will return a string. The original array will remain unmodified.

Comment: I think `join` uses a comma as a delimiter by default (you don't need to specify it)

Comment: @jbabey True, added just in case OP will need something else... :)

Comment: @Yury Tarabanko is this jquery or Ecmascript map function? I see its not supported in IE8 for ecmascript.

Comment: @Spring jquery version for oldfag browsers added.

Comment: @Yury Tarabanko tnx but I ended up using underscore map :)

Comment: @Spring If you have underscore use `_.pluck(companies, "companyId").join()` :)

Comment: @Yury Tarabanko what is the difference between _.map ?

Comment: No difference actually just more specific method to project data in arrays.

Answer (score 1):

Try [$.makeArray()](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.makeArray/)

> Convert an array-like object into a true JavaScript array.

```
var expectedStringResult = $.makeArray(company.companyId).join();
```

Comment: it returns nothing :)

Comment: srry no time for that