# youtube api: get view count of videos in a 'search list' request

Tags: javascript, youtube, youtube-api

I am using the Youtube Javascript API to retrieve a set of videos matching a search string.

It's working great, but I can't seem to find a way to get the statistics (esp. view count) of each video returned in the results.

I didn't find any mention of result statistics in the API [documentation](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/search/list).

Is this possible, or do I have to do an individual query for each returned id?

**CODE**

```
function init() {
    gapi.client.setApiKey(API_KEY);
    gapi.client.load('youtube', 'v3');
}

function search() {
        var q = $('#query').val();

        var request = gapi.client.youtube.search.list({
            q: q,
            part: 'snippet',
            type: 'video'
        });

        request.execute(function(response) {
            var str = JSON.stringify(response.result);
            $('#search-container').html('<pre>' + str + '</pre>');
        });
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> do I have to do an individual query for each returned id?

No ! You only need to make only one another request with the result of your previous request.

**1 -** Actually you have this :

```
var request = gapi.client.youtube.search.list({
            q: q,
            part: 'snippet',
            type: 'video'
        });

        request.execute(function(response) {
            var str = JSON.stringify(response.result);
            $('#search-container').html('<pre>' + str + '</pre>');
        });
```

This request give you the `id` of some YouTube video.

**2 -** Then you need to concatenate all this video's ID separated with a comma.

Example : `'P95nErnCoC4, 1d6z0gyA5ys'` See this post: [Create comma-delimited string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5166385/create-comma-delimited-string)

**3 -**  You need to create another request with the ressource [videos.list](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/videos/list)

```
var request = gapi.client.youtube.search.list({
            part: 'statistics',
            id: 'P95nErnCoC4, 1d6z0gyA5ys, id_next.....' //concatenate ID
        });

        request.execute(function(response) {
            console.log(response);
        });
```

Then you have statistics in only one more request.

Answer (score 1):

The above poster has the right concept but is issuing the wrong request the "part: 'statistics'" is not accessible through "gapi.client.youtube.search.list" request.

in order to access the statistics parameter you need to use the "gapi.client.youtube.videos.list" request which can provide all the meta data.

this request has access to the analytics api which i think is bundled with the v3 client api. great working example is as follows:
https://developers.google.com/youtube/analytics/v1/code_samples/javascript