# Efficient way of concatenating string variables and separating them by comma- Jaavscript/ES6

Tags: javascript

I know there are multiple ways of string concatenation and join them.
I have 3 string variables:

```
grp1= "hellp";
grp2= "world";
grp3= "all good";
```

I'm trying to concatenate them :

```
grp1.concat(grp2) || "", (grp3) || "");
```

however this does not give me commas, so i tried this:

```
grp1.concat(", ").concat(grp2, grp3);
```

however this gives me only one string separated by comma,

any better ways to concate and join string variables ?

Comment: Use “join”?! That’s what it’s for.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Create comma-delimited string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5166385/create-comma-delimited-string)

Comment: So are you trying to avoid `null/undefined` with your `||`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put them in an array and use [`Array.join()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/join).

```js
let grp = ["hellp","world","all good"];

let result = grp.join(", ");

console.log(result);
```